# Reliably Finding the Number of Holes in an Object

Tags: image-processing, image-segmentation, morphological-analysis

I'm currently using MATLAB's `bweuler` function to find the number of "holes" in an object.  I'm having difficulty due to the relatively low resolution of these images, currently only achieving a 50% success rate.  Here is an example of an image that will fail (cropped for testing convenience):

[image: failure image 1]

Normalized and scaled up so that you can see what's going on:

[image]

The number of holes should be 1 here, but I haven't found a reliable way to threshold that small area out while leaving its surroundings intact.

My current method uses an adaptive threshold, but this is problematic because the correct window size is not constant across all samples.  For instance, this example will work with a window size of 6, but others will fail.

For reference, here are a couple more failure cases:

N=1 -> [image: failure image 2]

N=2 -> [image]

And a few cases my current method handles:

N=6 -> [image: success image 1]

N=1 -> [image: success image 2]

N=1 -> [image: success image 3]

I'll post a short version of my current code as well, though as I said previously, I do not believe that an adaptive thresholding method will work.  I will be playing with some other morphological segmentation methods in the meantime. Just read one of the test images in and call `findholes(image)`.

```
function N = findholes(I)    
    bw = imclearborder(adaptivethreshold(I, 9));      
    N = abs(1 - bweuler(bw2, 4));
end

function bw=adaptivethreshold(IM,ws,C,tm)
    %ADAPTIVETHRESHOLD An adaptive thresholding algorithm that seperates the
    %foreground from the background with nonuniform illumination.
    %  bw=adaptivethreshold(IM,ws,C) outputs a binary image bw with the local 
    %   threshold mean-C or median-C to the image IM.
    %  ws is the local window size.
    %  C is a constant offset subtracted from the final input image to im2bw (range 0...1).
    %  tm is 0 or 1, a switch between mean and median. tm=0 mean(default); tm=1 median.
    %
    %  Contributed by Guanglei Xiong (xgl99@mails.tsinghua.edu.cn)
    %  at Tsinghua University, Beijing, China.
    %
    %  For more information, please see
    %  http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/adpthrsh.htm

    if (nargin < 2)
        error('You must provide IM and ws');
    end

    if (nargin<3)
        C = 0;
        tm = 0;
    end

    if (nargin==3)
        tm=0;
    elseif (tm~=0 && tm~=1)
        error('tm must be 0 or 1.');
    end

    IM=mat2gray(IM);

    if tm==0
        mIM=imfilter(IM,fspecial('average',ws),'replicate');
    else
        mIM=medfilt2(IM,[ws ws]);
    end
    sIM=mIM-IM-C;
    bw=im2bw(sIM,0);
    bw=imcomplement(bw);
end
```

Comment: How do you locate these blobs from the full image. Are you sure to have just one object in a call to findholes? Have a look at imregionalmin, it might give you some ideas.

Comment: @Ashish: I have a solid segmentation routine at this point, so we can assume that `findholes` will only ever have to deal with a single object.  I have actually played around with `imregionalmax` (something like `BW = imregionalmax(I); n = sum(BW(:));`), but it hasn't proven to be as reliable as I hoped.  That said, I left that solution behind some time ago and it may do well to revisit it with some further pre-processing on the image.

Comment: Ed - imregionalmin seems to find the center of the holes 'sometimes', but maybe with tweaking and preprocessing it gets better. I'll see if I play a bit with your sample images.

Comment: @Ashish: After revisiting `imregionalmin` armed with some better pre-processing techniques it's actually doing a pretty good job.  If you post that as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Ed, glad that worked better. It might be best for others in the same boat as you, if you posted on how you got imregionalmin working (I believe its ok to accept your own answers).